# Может ли NULL давать не нулевое значение?

Tags: c, null

При программировании часто использую подобное выражение:

```
if (pointer) {
    ....
}
```

что эквивалентно (по крайней мере для моей системы):

```
if (pointer != NULL)
```

где `pointer` указатель. Хочу удостовериться, что этот код не несет в себе опасности на других системах и т.д. В учебнике нашел только, что NULL возвращает значение не указывающее ни на какой объект. Но равно ли это значение `0` априори?

Comment: Насколько я знаю - всегда. Null дефайнится в 0 в залоговочном файле и все. Если вопрос о стиле кода - лучше пишите прямо с !=.

Comment: [When was the NULL macro not 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597142/when-was-the-null-macro-not-0)

Comment: [Checking for NULL pointer in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825668/checking-for-null-pointer-in-c-c)

Comment: По поводу стиля, первая форма ИМХО предпочтительнее, особенно в варианте `if (!pointer)`, ибо `if (pointer == NULL)` чревато опечаткой с одним `=` и всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Comment: @Fat-Zer невозможность опечатки устраняется через yoda-style, да и компиляторы детектят такое на ура.

Comment: @alexolut, yoda-style меня почему-то вымораживает, а компиляторы начали об этом предупреждать не так уж давно... на самом деле на 95% всё это чистой воды вкусовщина =)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Также внесу некоторые дополнения к ответам, которые дали @alexolut и @VladD.

Как вообще C решает истинно выражение `expression` в операторе `if` или нет:

```
if ( expression ) statement
if ( expression ) statement else statement
```

?

Пункт 6.8.4.1 / 2 говорит следующее:

> In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0. In the else form, the second substatement is executed if the expression compares equal to 0. [...]

То есть, выражение `expression` сравнивается с нулём. Если оно не равно нулю, то выражение `expression` считается истинным, если оно равно нулю, то `expression` считается ложным.

Таким образом, примеры в вашем вопросе интерпретируются так:

```
if (  pointer != 0  )
if ( (pointer != NULL) != 0 )
```

В стандарте языка явно оговорено (6.3.2.3 / 3), что и `0`, и `(void *)0`, и `NULL` — нулевые указательные константы (*null pointer constant*). Для целей сравнения указателя и нулевой указательной константы, нулевая указательная константа преобразуется к типу указателя (6.5.9 / 5):

> [...] If one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant, the null pointer constant is converted to the type of the pointer. [...]

Результат такого преобразования — нулевой указатель (*null pointer*). Если `pointer` не является нулевым указателем, то согласно пункту 6.5.9 / 6, оба выражения: `pointer != 0` и `pointer != NULL` — истинны.

Некоторого пояснения заслуживает выражение `(pointer != NULL) != 0`. Относительно операторов `!=` и `==` стандарт языка говорит следующее (6.5.9 / 3):

> [...] Each of the operators yields *1* if the specified relation is *true*  and *0* if it is *false*. The result has type `int`. [...]

Таким образом, если `pointer` — не является нулевым указателем, то выражение `(pointer != NULL)` — равно `1`, а значит выражение `(pointer != NULL) != 0` истинно.

Answer (score 5):

В дополнение к ответу @alexolut отмечу, что битовое представление нулевого указателя не обязательно состоит из всех нулевых битов.

Тем не менее, даже при таком представлении выражение `(void*)0` должно давать нулевой указатель (то есть, приведение типов должно менять внутреннее представление), а также сравнение с нулём (`if (p == 0)`) и проверка `if (p)` должны работать ожидаемым образом.

Comment: Ох, @VladD, прошу прощения за неверное написание вашего ника.

Comment: @wololo: Ничего страшного! С Новым Годом!

Answer (score 4):

Из стандарта языка С11, 6.3.2.3/3:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.

Таким образом проверка на 0 эквивалентна проверке на NULL.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на стэковерфлоу на русском!

Comment: @АндрейNOP too slow ;)